# Can't flash big binaries using dfu-util/pydfu to STM32H743VIT6

Tags: stm32, programming, flash

I have a board that uses STM32H743VIT6 (same as OpenMV4) that I can't flash binaries bigger than (500-600KB) to it although it has 2MB of flash.

Smaller binaries seems to be flashed OK, I am using the USB port of the STM32H743 with BOOT0 pin toggling and using dfu-util and pydfu (micropython implementation).

Any idea what might be wrong?

With pydfu an error appears around 700KB:

```
$ make BOARD=BOARD_1 deploy
Writing BOARD_1/firmware.dfu to the board
python3 ../../tools/pydfu.py --vid 0x0483 --pid 0xDF11 -u build-BOARD_1/firmware.dfu
File: build-BOARD_1/firmware.dfu
    b'DfuSe' v1, image size: 959405, targets: 1
    b'Target' 0, alt setting: 0, name: "ST...", size: 959120, elements: 2
      0, address: 0x08000000, size: 20560
      1, address: 0x08040000, size: 938544
    usb: 0483:df11, device: 0x0000, dfu: 0x011a, b'UFD', 16, 0x56f7fb3b
Writing memory...
0x08000000   20560 [=========================] 100% 
0x08040000  938544 [====================     ]  83% DFU: erase failed (STATE_DFU_DOWNLOAD_BUSY)
Makefile:571: recipe for target 'deploy' failed
make: *** [deploy] Error 1
```

A failed flash in dfu-util just gets stuck around 700KB:

```
$ dfu-util -a 0 -D firmware.dfu
dfu-util 0.9

Copyright 2005-2009 Weston Schmidt, Harald Welte and OpenMoko Inc.
Copyright 2010-2016 Tormod Volden and Stefan Schmidt
This program is Free Software and has ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
Please report bugs to http://sourceforge.net/p/dfu-util/tickets/

Match vendor ID from file: 0483
Match product ID from file: df11
Opening DFU capable USB device...
ID 0483:df11
Run-time device DFU version 011a
Claiming USB DFU Interface...
Setting Alternate Setting #0 ...
Determining device status: state = dfuIDLE, status = 0
dfuIDLE, continuing
DFU mode device DFU version 011a
Device returned transfer size 1024
DfuSe interface name: "Internal Flash   "
file contains 1 DFU images
parsing DFU image 1
image for alternate setting 0, (2 elements, total size = 959120)
parsing element 1, address = 0x08000000, size = 20560
Download    [=========================] 100%        20560 bytes
Download done.
parsing element 2, address = 0x08040000, size = 938544
Download    [====================     ]  82%       777216 bytes^C
```

Comment: because such things happen more often than people think: you're positive, from looking at the case of your MCU, that you actually have a STM32H743VI... and not a STM32H743VG...? Also, not a counterfeit that packaged a STM32H743VG... as an I... ?

Comment: It is a VIT6, STM32CubeProgrammer works correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems it is an issue with STM32H743 and flashing bank 2. It fails doing eras to that page (0x8100000), like shown here:
https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X0000CBk88MSQR/stm32h743-usb-dfu-cannot-write-to-flash-bank-2

The fix is to use mass erase, it fixes both dfu-util and pydfu:

```
./dfu-util -a 0 -S [serial number] -s :force:mass-erase:leave -v -D firmware.dfu
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wild speculation but,

The [errata to your chip](https://www.st.com/resource/en/errata_sheet/dm00368411-stm32h742xig-and-stm32h743xig-device-limitations-stmicroelectronics.pdf) say (2.2.17)

> The CRC result might be corrupted when FLASH CRC end address register for bank 1/2 (FLASH_CRCEADD1/2R) targets last address in sector 7.

The sector size of your flash is 128 kB, meaning that the address where writing fails, 0x08040000+777216, **is** in the 7.th sector of flash.

Maybe `dfu-util` checks the CRC, but your STM32CubeProgrammer doesn't? I haven't looked at its code in ages, and back then just because I wanted to know one special thing about the USB transactions, but the code was well-structured C. Might be worth simply taking a look at what happens in the Download procedure.

Comment: I read the code of pydfu and it doesn't use CRC at all for this. It gets stuck while doing erase for that page, page 0x8100000

`0x08040000  938544 [====================     ]  83% Erasing page: 0x8100000...
DFU: erase failed (STATE_DFU_DOWNLOAD_BUSY)`

Comment: Seems it is a known issue:
https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X0000CBk88MSQR/stm32h743-usb-dfu-cannot-write-to-flash-bank-2